# Column 'content' cannot be null : SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to do a simple example of one to many mapping in spring boot using this link

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

I have done as it is. I am the running the application and it is working fine.
But when I make a post request to http://localhost:8080/posts it starts giving me errors which I am unable to resolve.
The body I include while making a post request is:

```
   {
    "title": "Post 1",
    "description": "Post 1 Description",
    "content": "Post 1 Content"
   }
```

The error is :

```
 2020-06-22 15:57:38.838  WARN 20216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
 SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
 2020-06-22 15:57:38.838 ERROR 20216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
 Column 'content' cannot be null
2020-06-22 15:57:38.873 ERROR 20216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could 
not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

Post.java:

```
package com.example.jpa.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post extends AuditModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(unique = true)
private String title;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 250)
private String description;

@NotNull
@Lob
private String content;

public Object getTitle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void setTitle(Object title2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public Object getDescription() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void setDescription(Object description2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public Object getContent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void setContent(Object content2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

// Getters and Setters (Omitted for brevity)
}
```

PostController.java:

```
  package com.example.jpa.controller;

import com.example.jpa.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.example.jpa.model.Post;
import com.example.jpa.repository.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class PostController {

@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

@GetMapping("/posts")
public Page<Post> getAllPosts(Pageable pageable) {
    return postRepository.findAll(pageable);
}

@PostMapping("/posts")
public Post createPost(@Valid @RequestBody Post post) {
    return postRepository.save(post);
}

@PutMapping("/posts/{postId}")
public Post updatePost(@PathVariable Long postId, @Valid @RequestBody Post postRequest) {
    return postRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
        post.setTitle(postRequest.getTitle());
        post.setDescription(postRequest.getDescription());
        post.setContent(postRequest.getContent());
        return postRepository.save(post);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
}


@DeleteMapping("/posts/{postId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deletePost(@PathVariable Long postId) {
    return postRepository.findById(postId).map(post -> {
        postRepository.delete(post);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + postId + " not found"));
}

}
```

First is column content cannot be null. But as you can see while making a post request content coulmn is not null. Kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

may be Exception from mysql ,
please check "content" column data type is correct, (check date which are you passing to table is correct)

Answer (score 0):

The `getter setter` are not proper,

```
public String getContent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.content = content
    
}
```

Comment: The link that I am following, they did not have any getters and setters in their file. So should I remove them?

Comment: You need getters setter. You need to create for all the required fields

Comment: How can I do so? Sorry I am very new at Spring boot. Just righlt clicking on it and selecting generate getters and setters will do the work?

Comment: Yes.. select all the required fields and it would work